# "More than one MPM loaded" when trying to start apache on Vagrant Ubuntu box

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, vagrant

Whenever I try `sudo apache2ctl start` I receive the following message:

```
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
Action '-k restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

When I check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, there are no entries for this error. The only mods being included seem to be in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`, and all I see listed there as related to "mpm" are:

1. mpm_prefork.conf
2. mpm_prefork.load

In `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`, there are the following listed:

1. mpm_event.conf
2. mpm_event.load
3. mpm_prefork.conf
4. mpm_prefork.load
5. mpm_worker.conf
6. mpm_worker.load

However, my `apache2.conf` file does not load those in mods-available directory.

This is new territory to me, so I may be totally looking in wrong place. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `grep -r mpm_ /etc/apache2` and ignore anything in the `*-available` subdirs.

Comment: All that are returned are in the mods-available directory.

Comment: Hm, my bad. That would not help at all. - Weird, it would actually appear that each MPM has a distinct binary on Debian/Ubuntu. It's unclear how that error can occur. Have you tried removing all `apache2-mpm-*` packages except for prefork?

Comment: Here it is mid-2015 and I'm getting the same problem with Vagrant+Ubuntu. There is only one module being loaded. I think what changed was that I did an apt-get update. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @cillosis This just happened to me too.. all solutions to this problem don't work for this case. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This cannot happen in Apache v2.2 (which the question is tagged as), it can only happen in Apache v2.4 where you can compile the three `MPMs` as dynamically loadable modules.

Search all your configuration files for the following three lines. The paths maybe different of course, depending on your installation. There can only ever be one of these three modules actually loaded. If more than one are present and uncommented you will get the error you mention:

```
# Only *ONE* of these modules may be uncommented in a valid configuration
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
```

If you somehow managed to get an Apache installation with one of the `MPMs` compiled into the httpd binary itself *and* with one or more of the `MPMs` as a loadable module then you might also get this.

Run `/path/to/httpd -l` to see if there is an `MPM` built in and then search for the above lines as before